# Android Studio - Change applicationId in build.gradle file

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

How can I change the `applicationId` field of my `build.gradle` file?

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.oldname.appname"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

I've already renamed the package structure to `com.newname.appname` and all the imports and things like that have updated, but `applicationId` hasn't. I can't refactor it and just trying to type in a new name brings up a ton of errors where Android Studio will tell me my main `FragmantActivity` "is not applicable to android.app.Activity" and so on.

Any idea what to do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @CommonsWare I thought the errors did pertain to `applicationId`, since as soon as I changed that and only that, the errors went away. Previously, I tried a resyncing gradle, doing a clean build, and restarting Android Studio but nothing worked.

Answer (score 5):

You can create different flavours for one application in Gradle file. This will increase the code reusability.

An example for an application with Paid and Free flavors:

```
productFlavors {

    paid {
        applicationId "com.oldname.appname.paid"
    }

    free {
        applicationId "com.oldname.appname.free"
    }

}
```

So these two flavours will act as two products. You can upload it to play store as different applications.

You can also get four build variant for this two flavours.

com.oldname.appname.free- debug

com.oldname.appname.free- release

com.oldname.appname.paid- debug

com.oldname.appname.paid- release

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the usual java files and manifest that had to be renamed I had to also change the settings under Project Structure:

SO I went to File > Project Structure > Modules/app > Flavours

I then changed the Application ID and all worked great.

Hope this helps for other MAC users like myself.  (Did not test on Windows)

Comment: In addition to that I went to google-services.json and changed the package name as well in all occurrences to match the one I have in AndroidManifest and applicationid -> build gradle.